# How can you set the XData of a Matlab line graph plot with a 2D array?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm having some issues dynamically changing the data that is displayed on a plot. The data set is stored in a 2D array of varying dimensions, during the running of the program, only the width of the matrix will change - all elements always have the same length. The intention here is to have each row of the matrix represented by a line on the line plot.

An example:

```
data = [1, 2, 3; 3, 4, 5; 4, 5, 6];
p = plot(data);
drawnow;

new_data = [7, 8, 9; 1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6];
set(p, 'XData', new_data);
drawnow;
```

This method works well for updating plots when the data is better formatted, however I cannot seem to find a way to organise the data in a useful format that will allow this to plot.

Comment: just a remark: MATLAB is _column major_. It means that if you send a matrix as input into `plot`, it will plot one `line` per **column** of your matrix. The `transpose` function (shorthand notation: `.'`) can arrange your matrix if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To set multiple properties (as `p` is an array of handles to line objects), the *property name* as well as the properties to set need to be cell arrays, see e.g. [this documentation page](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) under "Set Line Style to Different Value for Multiple Lines" for an example.

In your example case, this would work:

```
set(p, {'XData'}, mat2cell(new_data, ones(1,3), 3));
```

See also [`mat2cell`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), in this case I use it to reshape `new_data` to a 3x1 cell array each containing a 1x3 row from `new_data`.